# mypy type checking shows error when a variable gets dynamically allocated

Tags: pyspark, python-3.7, mypy

I have a class that takes a `Spark DataFrame` and does some processing to it. Here is the code:

```
    for column in self.sdf.columns:
        if column not in self.__columns:
            row = [column]
            row += '--' * 9
            column_table.append(row)
```

I have this code inside constructor of my class:

```
self.sdf: Optional[SparkDataFrame] = None
```

Here `sdf` is set dynamically during execution of my class and then the for loop mentioned above will run. `__columns` is a dictionary which is supposed to have all the columns of sdf. I found no errors in the code when it ran. But when I type checked my code with `mypy`, it showed an error on the first line of for loop:

`error: Item "None" of "Optional[Any]" has no attribute "columns"`

I understand that initially sdf will be `None`. But should I consider this a serious error? Is there are any workarounds for this?

Comment: I don't pretend to understand why, but for a custom class attribute I stopped mypy giving that error by changing `self.thing: Optional[OtherClass] = None` to `self.thing: OtherClass = None`

Comment: Ah, the reason why my commented solution "worked" was because mypy wasn't actually working properly. For that project I needed `mypy --explicit-package-bases --namespace-packages`. So my solution doesn't actually work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `columns` is  specific to data frame. you can find more info [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.columns) .When you set self.sdf is None, you will get the error you posted. you can alternatively try this.

```
    from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

    if self.sdf is not None and isinstance(self.sdf,DataFrame):
        for column in self.sdf.columns:
            if column not in self.__columns:
                row = [column]
                row += '--' * 9
                column_table.append(row)
```